# Stop table from overlapping while loop through worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on VBA to loop through each worksheet on a workbook, determine used ranges and format as tables. Here is the code I've found and has been trying to use:

```
Sub loop_test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim StartCell As Range, TblRng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
    Dim objTable As ListObject

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Set objTable = Nothing
        With ws
            Set StartCell = .Range("A1")
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            LastColumn = .Cells(StartCell.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


            Set TblRng = .Range(StartCell, .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

            ' Test if table exists on sheet
            On Error Resume Next
            Set objTable = .ListObjects(1)
            On Error GoTo 0

            ' If table overlaps with TblRng - Convert to Range
            If Not Intersect(objTable.Range, TblRng) Is Nothing Then
                objTable.Unlist
            End If

            ' Create Table
            Set objTable = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, TblRng, , xlYes)

            'Styling
            objTable.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"

        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

When I run it, I get a "91" error: "Object variable or With block variable not set". Debugging leads me to line 21:
`If Not Intersect(objTable.Range, TblRng) Is Nothing Then`

When I commented it out, it works until the ranges overlap. How do I make sure `objTable` is defined once I run the macro in the beginning?

Comment: You have to first check `If Not objTable Is Nothing`... there's the possibility that the worksheet has no table.

Comment: Instead of using `On Error Resume Next`... `On Error GoTo 0`, you could just use `If .ListObjects.Count > 0` to check if the worksheet contains a `ListObject`.

Comment: Thank you @BigBen, but how do I go about adding the If statement to the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first check `If Not objTable Is Nothing`... there's the possibility that the worksheet has no table.

```vb
' First check that table actually exists:
If Not objTable Is Nothing Then
    ' If table overlaps with TblRng - Convert to Range
    If Not Intersect(objTable.Range, TblRng) Is Nothing 
        objTable.Unlist
    End If
End If
```

---

Instead of using `On Error Resume Next`...`On Error GoTo 0`, you can simplify checking if the worksheet contains a table. One approach is checking if the `.ListObjects.Count > 0`.

```vb
If .ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
    ....
End If
```

Or you could use a `For Each` loop in case you have multiple tables on the sheet:

```vb
Dim tbl As ListObject
For Each tbl In .ListObjects

If Not Intersect(tbl.Range, TblRng) Is Nothing Then
    tbl.Unlist
End If
```